# HTTP Error 404.15 not found - Identity 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, identity

I am trying to use the ASP.Net Identity 2 in a ASP.Net MVC 5 web application

When I run my application I have the following screen:

[image]

Startup.Auth.css

```
     public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
    }
```

I have a Interruption Point in the Login Action but there is not any call to it. When I disable the code in StartUp.Auth class the application runs but the authentication stops working.

I don't know what is the problem. I have another application running with the same features.

This is the URL that is generated:

```
 http://localhost:23928/Home/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FHome%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FHome%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FHome%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FHome%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FHome%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FHome%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FHome%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FHome%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FHome%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FHome%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FHome%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FHome%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FHome%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FHome%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FHome%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FHome%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FHome%25252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FHome%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FHome%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252FHome%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solve the problem. I had the Windows Authentication enabled.

Open the 'Properties' panel on the right

Set 'Windows Authentication' to 'Disabled'

Set 'Anonymous Authentication' to 'Enabled'

Comment: I would like to add that in my project I had to open a dedicated configuration file for the connected IIS EXPRESS, as soon as I changed it in the file to only use windows authentication it work (I found the configuration file through the IIS express helper that is open while you configure the project)
you have to change some xml that looks like
<location path="ProjectName"><system.webServer><security>
<authentication>                    
<anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />